# Photoshop CS5 Type Tool frustration!

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5, typesetting

So I choose the type tool and key in 2 words. I want to change the the 2nd word to a different color. I select the second word and change its color on the Options bar. The following strangeness happens: the 2nd word changes color to what i just picked. Then it automatically gets highlighted and disappears completely, as thought you deleted it on purpose.

Is there a setting or something thats making it do that?? Please help. This is making my type edits a nightmare.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you alter the selected words in other ways? Such as not change colour, but size, font etc?

Comment: no i can't. The same thing happens.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me... What I would try is to make sure your cache memory and/or RAM isn't near full, use Edit > Purge to clear cache memory. Otherwise, a re-install of Photoshop might help.

Comment: I vote for bug too. Test similar scenario in a new document. Restart, reset preferences, clear cache. If that does not help, reinstall.

Comment: @boblet Why not turn your comment into an answer so that the question can show as answered and Roon can accept it?

Comment: This problem also occurred to me several times in CC 13. Seems to be fixed in CC 14. I remember vaguely that it didn’t happen when I changed the properties via the Character Panel.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for it being a bug too. Try some standard troubleshoot before doing anything drastic.

- Restart PS.
- Test similar scenario in a brand new document.
- Copy the original document and give it a different name, and then
  test that (yes it sounds stupid, but sometimes the stupid work)
- Take some of the elements you have over in a new document and test
  again.
- Reset preferences, clear cache

These are the ones I can come up with, there might be other steps, but if all these fails, reinstall.